# Error cordova 'Requeriments Check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater'

Tags: java, android

Hola amigos tengo un error al compilar con Quasar una aplicacion de cordova me dice que el jdk que tengo esta desactualizado o algo asi, que requiero la 1.8 o mayor pero tengo la version 10.0.1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: probablemente funcione con jdk 1.8 y no los posteriores

Comment: Fíjate que dice que la verificación de requisitos falló para JDK 1.8 o superior, así que quizás solo funcione con versiones anteriores.

Comment: Generalmente cunado se compila una aplicación java se establece por defecto la versión del JVM con la que se construyo la misma, por lo que a la hora de ejecutarlo en otra PC, esta debe tener al menos la misma versión de java. Esto se configura en las propiedades de la aplicación dentro del IDE usado. Esto sucede porque las librerías usadas no coinciden o son muy viejas y así evitas conflicto de ejecución.

Comment: Es cierto, instale la 1.8 y me funciono!